# Insert data to database from excel

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Using `codeigniter`'s excel class I have displayed data from `excel.xls`:

```
echo $worksheetrows->dump(true,true);
```

But I am confused how to insert this data to database. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
    A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   J
```

1   Number Formats  123456789.123
2   Format  Positive    Negative Format 1   Negative Format 2   Negative Format 3   Negative Format 4
3   1234    123456789   -123456789  123456789   (123456789) (123456789)     Col I is hidden -->
4   1234.0  123456789.1 -123456789.1    123456789.1 (123456789.1)   (123456789.1)           This is col J
5   1234.00 123456789.12    -123456789.12   123456789.12    (123456789.12)  (123456789.12)
6   1,234   123,456,789 -123,456,789    123,456,789 (123,456,789)   (123,456,789)
7   1,234.0 123,456,789.1   -123,456,789.1  123,456,789.1   (123,456,789.1) (123,456,789.1)
8   1,234.00    123,456,789.12  -123,456,789.12 123,456,789.12  (123,456,789.12)    (123,456,789.12)
9   $1,234.00   $123,456,789.12 $-123,456,789.12    $123,456,789.12 ($123,456,789.12)   ($123,456,789.12)
10  Dates   Times           Percentages Fonts
11  12/31/2008  11/11/2008 10:55    1/1/09 1:44:59 am   23:00:00    50% Bold
12  02/03/08    10:55:48 am 1/1/09 1:45:00 am   23:30:00    1.23%   Italic
13  12/31   10:55:48    1/1/09 1:45:01 am           Underline
14  December 31, 2008   12/01/2009              Bold - Italic
15  Wednesday, December 31, 2008                    Bold - Underline
16  31-Dec                  italic - Underline
17  Colors
18  Red Green   Blue    Yellow  Gray    Orange  Purple  Cyan

Comment: Why are you using echo? Use var_dump() to see what $worksheetrows->dump(true,true); gives you, as it should be an array

Comment: $worksheetrows->dump(true,true); shows the exact data from excel sheet. But how to insert it.

Comment: So can you show us an example of what it looks like? I find it hard to believe that a spreadsheet can be echoed like a simple string

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/

Comment: So it's generating HTML markup - in that case, you'll either need to parse the HTML to extract the contents from each td, or use a different library with codeigniter that gives you the ability to access the data as an array. Personally, I'd recommend the latter, though I have a vested interest as author of a library for doing just that

Comment: ok... can you please help me to find out codeigniter library  for excel reader

Comment: First google response: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/PHPExcel --- second google response: http://www.ahowto.net/php/easily-integrateload-phpexcel-into-codeigniter-framework

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array(
   'title' => 'My title' ,
   'name' => 'My Name' ,
   'date' => 'My date'
);

$this->db->insert('mytable', $data);

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date')
```

[From](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert)

Comment: but this code for insertion. I need to insert data from excel sheet